# Form button CSS

Tags: html, css

im new to HTML and im just trying to edit a template at the moment. A Sign Up button on an unordered list has thrown me.

Heres some info:

On the template i had to change the link to a form button in order to integrate it opening up a part of the account system... After i placed the form button there it turned out like this:
https://gyazo.com/82c807d59162ada63dcaeea69b2fd340

The old code looked like this:

```
<li><a href="#">Sign Up Now!</a></li>
```

And the new code looks like this:

```
<li><button type="button" class="order-button" data-product="1" >Sign Up Now!</a></li>
```

I also had to insert this into the footer in the code to integrate it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#"></script>
```

I've taken the links out just for anonymity.

Also the bottom part of the list where it now says "Sign Up Now!" is supposed to be green and then turn to black on the mouseover.

The CSS files from the template are quite extensive though and the section with all of the .btn CSS parts is just a long unstructured list thats hard to make sense of. And on top of that i cant work out how to link the form button to the .btn part of the CSS.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Why didn't you just style the link to look like a button?

Answer (score 1):

Your markup has an incorrect closing tag for `<button>`. It should be:

```
<li><button type="button" class="order-button" data-product="1" >Sign Up Now!</button></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to add your custom css at the end of the CSS file.
Thay way you could add this class:

```css
.order-button{

   /* Styles for button here */
  
}

.order-button:hover{
  
   /* Styles for mouseover here */
  
}
```

Comment: Also, you mention you want to "link the form button to the .btn part of the code" Do you mean you want to give it those styles? If that's the case you need to add the "btn" class to the button as well

Comment: You can add more than one class like this: <button class="btn order-button">Sign Up Now!</button>